# Laravel 8 - Why not get data in the view

Tags: database, view, laravel-8

I want to get the name of the images in the trip version in show.blade.php
but for some reason I can't get someone to help me

**App\Models\Images**

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Images extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = [
        'id',
        'name',
        'trip_id',
    ];

    public function trip()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Trip::class);
    }

}
```

**App\Models\Trip**

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Trip extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = [
        'title',
        'place',
        'tripcontent',
        'user_id'
    ];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function images()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Images::class);
    }


}
```

**App\Http\Controllers\TripController**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Trip;
use App\Models\Images;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Intervention\Image\Facades\Image;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

    public function show(Trip $trip)
    {

        return view('trip.show')->with([
            'trip' => $trip,
           ]);


    }
```

**resources\views\trip\show.blade.php**

```
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 mt-2">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="/img/trip/{{ $trip->images->name}}.jpg"">
                
            </div>
```

That's how I want to get the data in view
$trip-> images-> name

Someone can help